# How to do Devise reset password mail customization?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, devise

i m using devise for authentication purpose, for reset password its send email like bellow

Hello there,

```
if you would like to reset or if you have forgotten your password please click on the      following link: click_here

Thank you and happy bantering!
the swagata@gmail.com Regards
```

i want last line looks like

```
regards 
the swagata@gmail.com
```

please give me some suggestion

Answer (score 2):

You can customize the devise views. Run the following command in your project directory:

```
rails g devise:views
```

This will copy devise views (including mailer templates) in your `app/views/devise` directory. Then you can customize as you want.

Comment: Specifically, after running `rails g devise:views`, the template you want to edit is `app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb` or ``app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.haml`